# Find $a$, $b$, and $c$ so that $y=ax^2+bx+c$ passes through $(1,2)$, $(-1,6)$, and $(2,3)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the values of $a$, $b$, and $c$ so that the graph of the polynomial $P(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ passes through the points $(1,2)$, $(-1,6)$, and $(2,3)$.

I tried

$\begin{eqnarray}
a+2b+c & = & 2\\
a+6b+c & = & 6\\
4a+3b+c & = & 3
\end{eqnarray}$

I try to use those values in a matrix but I can't get the values for $a$, $b$, and $c$.  I don't know.  Maybe my way to solve it is wrong.

Comment: How did you get those equations? In particular, check the coefficients of the $B$ terms.

Comment: from this P(x)=ax^2+bx+c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After plugging in each point's $x$-coordinate and setting the quadratic equal to the $y$-coordinate, I have the following system:
$$
a+b+c=2 \\
a-b+c=6 \\
4a+2b+c=3
$$
which has the corresponding matrix system:
$$A\vec{x} = \vec{b} \\ 
\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1 \\
1&-1&1 \\
4&2&1
\end{pmatrix} \vec{x} = \begin{pmatrix}
2 \\ 6 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}
$$
This can be reduced by [inverting the matrix $A$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=invert%20%5B%5B1%2C1%2C1%5D%2C%5B1%2C-1%2C1%5D%2C%5B4%2C2%2C1%5D%5D) to get
$$A^{-1} = \frac{1}{6} 
\begin{pmatrix}
-3 & 1 & 2 \\
3 & -3 & 0 \\
6 & 2 & -2
\end{pmatrix}$$
And the answer is $A^{-1}\vec{b} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}$ so your quadratic solution is $P(x) = x^2-2x+3$ and your values for $a,b,c$ are 1,-2,3, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is more easily solved if you first solve three much simpler problems:

- $P_1(1)=1,\enspace P_1(-1)=0,\enspace P_1(2)=0$
- $P_2(1)=0,\enspace P_2(-1)=1,\enspace P_2(2)=0$
- $P_3(1)=0,\enspace P_3(-1)=0,\enspace P_3(2)=1$

This is very simple because for each problem you have prescribed roots for $P_1, P_2, P_3$. Once you've found them, it's *very*  easy to find $P$:
\begin{align*}
P_1(x)&=\frac{(x+1)(x-2)}{(1+1)(1-2)}=\frac 12(-x^2+x+2)\\
P_2(x)&=\frac{(x-1)(x-2)}{(-1-1)(-1-2)}=\frac 1 6 (x^2-3x+2)\\
P_3(x)&=\frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{(2-1)(2+1)}=\frac 1 3(x^2-1)
\end{align*}

Now you'll just have to take:
$$P(x)=2P_1(x)+6P_2(x)+3P_3(x)=x^2-2x+3.$$

Let me add that for the analog problem for higher degree, e.g. finding a polynomial of degree $6$  whose representative curve passes through $7$ given points in the plane, it is much shorter than the method of indeterminate coefficients. It essentially relies on the fact `evaluation of polynomials`, that is the map $p(x)\mapsto p(\alpha)$ for a given $\alpha$, is a linear map.